# gulp.watch error: write after end

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I am getting different results for different `gulp.watch` instruction
When I execute my `watch` task and  change an `.html` file, everything works correctly (tasks defined below)

But when I change *any* other files (.coffee, .less, etc) I get this error:

```
stream.js:94

      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
Error: write after end
  at writeAfterEnd (/Users/oclement/Documents/phoenix/MedifastCerBrokenDown/MedifastWeb/AppSource/node_modules/gulp-filter/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:145:12)
  at Transform.Writable.write (/Users/oclement/Documents/phoenix/MedifastCerBrokenDown/MedifastWeb/AppSource/node_modules/gulp-filter/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:193:5)
  at Stream.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
  at Stream.emit (events.js:95:17)gulp.watch`
```

---

### Watch Task

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    isWatching = true;
    run('build', 'index', function() {
        g.util.log(g.util.colors.green('Starting to Watch'));
        gulp.watch('./app/**/*.html', ['templates']);
        gulp.watch('./app/**/*.coffee', ['phnxjs']);
        ...
    });
});
```

### Template Task

```
gulp.task('templates', function(done) {
    g.util.log(g.util.colors.green('---TEMPLATES---'));
    sourceStreams.templates()
        .pipe(buildWatchPipe()())
        .pipe(g.ngHtml2js(options.templates))
        .pipe(g.concat(destinations.templates.bundleName))
        .pipe(g.if(isProd, transformScriptsProd()))
        .pipe(destinations.templates.target())
        .pipe(g.if(isWatching, g.livereload()));
    done();
});
```

### Phnxjs Task

```
gulp.task('phnxjs', function(done) {
    g.util.log(g.util.colors.green('---PHNXJS---'));
    var wrapException = g.filter('!**/tags-input.js');

    sourceStreams.phoenixScripts()
        .pipe(buildWatchPipe()())
        .pipe(filters.coffee)
        .pipe(g.coffee(options.coffee))
            .on('error', g.util.log)
        .pipe(filters.coffee.restore())
        .pipe(wrapException)
            .pipe(iffeWrapper())
        .pipe(wrapException.restore())
        .pipe(g.if(!isProd, g.angularFilesort()))
        .pipe(g.if(isProd, transformScriptsProd()))
        .pipe(g.if(isProd, g.concat(destinations.phoenixScripts.bundleName)))
        .pipe(destinations.phoenixScripts.target())
        .pipe(g.if(isWatching, g.livereload()));

    done();
});
```

Comment: No problem, will delete my answer and re-open it if I see something else

Comment: Include your filter variable inside of the task.  See [How to watch gulp multiple files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645103/how-to-gulp-watch-multiple-files/29617943#answer-29617943