# gulp watch is not always working

Tags: javascript, gulp, watch

Sometimes gulp watch is not working when I save a javascript file.  This is my watch task below.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.js', ['js']);
});
```

I do have a bunch of sub directories.  Would it be advisable to make my watch task be more specific like:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/*.js', ['js']);
    gulp.watch('./src/dir1/**/*.js', ['js']);
    gulp.watch('./src/dir2/**/*.js', ['js']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your task slightly more specific.

With './src/**/*.js' you are only watching javascript files in sub folders, not in the first level of ./src/

Having  `gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.js', './src/*.js'], ['js'])` will work. Keep in mind watch can take an array of strings to watch for, don't call it multiple times.

Here's a similar question and answer:

[How to Gulp-Watch Multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645103/how-to-gulp-watch-multiple-files)

Comment: So far as I can tell this answer isn't correct. Gulp uses [minimatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimatch) library for globbing, so you can test it out:

`console.log(minimatch('./src/test.js', './src/**/*.js'))` outputs `true`.

Additionally, though I can't find documentation specific to the glob in Gulp, if you look at `**/*` in other contexts you will find this behaviour is normal. E.g. [zsh manual 14.8.6](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html): "note that this therefore matches files in the current directory as well as subdirectories".